# When is minimizing dual to solve constraint optimization problem a good/bad idea?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker, constraint-programming, non-convex-optimization

I want to solve the following constraint optimization problem for many different $\alpha$.
$$\theta^* = \underset{\theta}{\text{argmin}}\, f(\theta) \text{ s.t. } g(\theta) \leq \alpha$$
Motivated by the duality principle, I try to solve this instead for various $\mu$:
$$\hat\theta = \underset{\theta}{\text{argmin}}\, \left( f(\theta) + \mu g(\theta) \right)$$
I am trying to get a better handle on when this approach works or fails.

In particular, can we say that it works when $(f(\theta^*), g(\theta^*))$ is *convex*, i.e., will the curve $(f(\hat\theta), g(\hat\theta))$ be equivalent? Can we prove that it fails when $(f(\theta^*), g(\theta^*))$ is *concave*?